# Multiple aggregates in linq to entities (code first)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Given the following model, I want to be able to retrieve the number of points gained for a single player and the average number of point gained for all players given a time period. This should be done in a single db query (I also want other stats e.g. avg points per team which will come later but the concept should be the same).

Having a bad day and getting nowhere. Can someone help me out?

```
public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PlayerGame> PlayerGames { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class PlayerGame
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Points { get; set; }

    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public Player Player { get; set; }

    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public Game Game { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class Game
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Edit:

OK. Have taken the game entity out of the equation for now and changed your code to fit in with my repo. This is what I have now:

```
var query = from p in _playerRepository.Query()
                        from pg in p.PlayerGames
                        group new { p, pg } by 1 into ppg
                        select new
                        {
                            SinglePlayerPointsGained = (from x in ppg
                                                        where x.p.Id == playerId && x.pg.Date > startDateTime
                                                        select x.pg.Points).Sum(),
                            AveragePoints = (from x in ppg 
                                             where x.pg.Date > startDateTime
                                             select x.pg.Points).Average(),                            
                        };
```

So Now I just need the AveragePoints calculation to take players that have not played in the period into account as mentioned in the comment.

Comment: did you find a solution or encounter a problem with the proposed answer?

Comment: thx. still playing around with it. using a repository rather than context directly so adapted it slightly (no explicit joins - just multiple from statements instead) and it returns the data ok. the only issue is that the average is calculated for only those who played games during the time period whereas I need the average of all players, regardless of whether they played a game during the period. assuming this means not using Average() and calculating manually based on total points for period / total players but haven't got this working yet using a single statement. any ideas?

Comment: You just need to move the `datetime` `where` statement into the `SinglePlayerPointsGained` portion. I updated my answer - Is that what you are looking for? Also, it might be helpful if you update your question with the modifications you made

Comment: The AveragePoints still needs to take date into account but I want to include all players that did not play in the period in the average calculation. e.g. player1 scores 4, player 2 scores 5, player 3 does not play during that period. I want the average to be 9/3 = 3 rather than 9/2 = 4.5. Will update my question with the changes I have made. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed the `Game` class had a `DateTime` property. The basic idea is using the `group by 1` trick

```
DateTime startDateTime, endDateTime;

int playerId;

var query = from p in context.Players
            join pg in context.Players on p.Id equals pg.PlayerId
            join g in context.Games on pg.GameId equals g.Id               
            group new { p, pg, g } by 1 into ppgg
            select new {
               SinglePlayerPointsGained = (from x in ppgg
                                           where x.p.PlayerId == playerId
                                           where x.g.DateTime >= startDateTime && x.g.DateTime <= endDateTime
                                           select x.pg.Points ).Sum(),
               AveragePoints = (from x in ppgg
                                group x.pg.Points by x.p.PlayerId into g
                                select g.Key).Average()

            };
```